# How to numerically perform analytic continuation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, numerical-methods, analytic-functions, analytic-continuation

I understand that one can in theory analytically continue a function by repeatedly computing new Taylor series. Suppose for example we have an analytic function $f$ defined on some open set $U$ and compute

$$T_0(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!}(z-z_0)^n$$

for some $z_0\in U$ close to the boundary of $U$. If this converges on $V$ where $U\cap V$ is non-empty, we can then compute another Taylor series to extend further:

$$T_1(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{T_0^{(n)}(z_1)}{n!}(z-z_1)^n$$

for some $z_1\in V\setminus U$ etc.

However, it is impossible to compute infinitely many terms and higher derivatives quickly become prone to large amounts of cancellation error.

Furthermore, one must repeated drop the degree of the next series expansion, as demonstrated [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/imzzgdmvnp), in order for the result to be useful. Otherwise, with the same degree at the new point $z_1$, you will end up recovering the original $T_0$ and fail to approximate $f$ further away.

> So how can one actually numerically compute the analytic continuation of a function?

In my specific case, I have a set of data points over a subinterval of $\mathbb R$ and I know some basic behavior about the function $f$'s derivatives (all derivatives are positive over the subinterval and to the right, which is the area I want to continue to) and that it has no singularities to the right of the given subinterval.

Comment: You might look at this recent paper of Trefethen: [Quantifying the ill-conditioning of analytic continuation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.11097).

Comment: It would seem to me this kind of problem is harder the more I look into it. x.x

Comment: No, the analytic continuation is not continuous in the coefficients, looking at finitely coefficients doesn't work, you need explicit prior (such as "the function is analytic on those two disks and it is bounded by that function on each") to do numerical approximation. The key is that a bound for $f(z)$ on $|z-a|=r$ gives an upper bound for the accuracy of its Taylor polynomials at $a$ when evaluated for $|z-a| < r$.

Comment: It seems  you have an [Extrapolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrapolation) problem which is very difficult in general. If the data is well behaved you are very lucky.

Comment: @reuns I'm not sure where you are coming from or entirely what you are trying to say, but if you are talking about the marching method of repeatedly applying Taylor expansions as described here, then certainly convergence requires something such as that, otherwise you could have a singularity.

Comment: @Somos I figured the special case of extrapolating analytic functions, which is known to give unique results, to be numerically manageable, at least to some degree.

Comment: I made it perfectly clear: you need to know that the function is analytic and bounded on that domain. Then you can approximate it on the whole domain just from its Taylor polynomials at one point, the error is computable and depends on the domain and the bound. Without such knowledge you can't do anything.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, the power series centered at $z_o$ will involve powers of $z-z_o$, not $z$...

Comment: @paulgarrett my bad, edited.

Comment: @reuns It is clear what you said, but not what your point is. Are you asking if the I know the provided function is analytic and bounded in the regions I want to continue to?

Comment: **You need to know some information on the function: not only its Taylor polynomial at $z_0$, not only its radius of convergence, but also a radius of convergence on the other disks you want to look at and a bound for $|f|$ on those.**  Once you know this you can do numerical calculations with known error term. Without you can't.

Comment: @reuns Yes, I already understand that, there is no need to yell. As I pointed out at the end, I know there are singularities in the direction I am continuing, so I know the radii of convergence. I didn't mention that I knew a bound for the area I am searching, though from the context of where the function comes from, I can expect bounds (sublinear as $\Re(z)\to\infty$).

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/446163/numerical-analytic-continuation-asymptotics

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's often possible to increase the radius of convergence by applying a suitable conformal mapping to the series. The transform then moves singularities away to a larger distance from the point you are expanding around. For example, the conformal mapping:

$$z = \frac{p w}{p+1-w}\tag{1}$$

Keeps the points $z=0$ and $z=1$ fixed while it moves the point $z = -p$ to infinity, while the point at infinity, which is often a singular point, is moved to $w = p+1$.

Even if only a few terms of the series expansion of a function are known, then we can apply such a conformal transform to evaluate the function outside the radius of convergence. Take e.g. the series for $\log(1+2 z)$:

$$\log(1+2 z) = 2 z - 2 z^2 +\frac{8 z^3}{3}-4 z^4+\frac{32 z^5}{5}-\frac{32 z^6}{3}+\frac{128 z^7}{7} -32 z^8 +\frac{512 z^9}{9} -\frac{512 z^{10}}{5}\cdots$$

This series has a radius of convergence of $\frac{1}{2}$, so it seems that we cannot use this series to evaluate  $\log(1+2 z)$ at $z = 1$. However, we can use this series by applying the conformal mapping (1) for e.g. $p = 1$. This yields the series:

$$w + \frac{w^3}{12} + \frac{w^5}{80} + \frac{w^7}{448} + \frac{w^9}{2304}+\cdots$$

The point $z = 1$ corresponds to $w = 1$, and it's clear that the series converges very fast for $w = 1$, while the original series was divergent at $z = 1$. Note that the computation of this series involves just the substitution of (1) in the series and then a re-expansion in powers of $w$ to order 10.

Comment: That is actually really interesting and simple. Do you have anything I could read up on about it?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I'll expand this answer and add some references to the literature. These sorts of methods were used in a rudimentary form already by Euler as a means to give meaning to divergent summations. There are many different approaches to this problem, Mathematicians have more focused on getting to a notion of summability that would then also apply to divergent series, while in physics people were more concerned with doing practical computations. Perturbation theory is a frequently used tool in physics, resummation methods are a popular tool within this field.

Comment: Are you referring to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_summation) from Euler?

Comment: In mathematics, perturbation theory is used in a more rigorous way, which then limits its use to the conditions under which it has been derived (the "small parameter" will always remain small). In the mathematics literature you then don't read much about the techniques that theoretical physicist have devised in the last few decades. In physics we don't have much problems with attacking a numerical math problem where there is no small parameter by pretending that there is one, expanding in powers of that parameter, and then using resummation methods to deal with large values of that parameter.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Yes, I think this corresponds to the mapping $$z(w) = \frac{2 w}{1-w}$$

Comment: I suspected as much when I first read this, but this seems to be far more generally applicable.

Comment: A modern, refined way to go about resumming series is [the order dependent mapping method](https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.0675).There is also another method due to Kleinert and Janke, [see here](https://hagenkleinert.de/documents/articles/228.pdf), which also amounts to smuggling in an auxiliary parameter in the series, but that parameter then originates form the problem at hand.

Comment: Very interesting. I don't quite understand what are the properties that are required from the conformal transformation. For example, assume you know the singularities of $f(z)$ are at infinity (essential) and poles on the imaginary axis. What should the best conformal transformation look like?

Comment: @lcv You want to maximize the radius of convergence, so that means that the singularity closest to the origin after applying the transform should be at a maximum distance, But this is not so easy to implement, in most cases we don't know where the poles of the function are, Zinn-Justin has shown that if you use the transform $x = p z/(1-z)$ to find the expansion around infinity from the expansion around zero then equating the largest power to zero and choosing the largest value for p yields the fastest converging series, because larger p corresponds to a larger radius of convergence.

Comment: @SaibalMitra Thank you very much, very helpful! I may ask a separate question.

Comment: @SaibalMitra I posted a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4601916/numerical-analytic-continuation-for-tanh-like-function) of which you may know the answer

Comment: @lcv Thanks for asking me. I have an idea that looks like working for that case. I'll write it up later today.

Comment: @SaibalMitra thank you, that seems amazing.

Answer (score 3):

*Too longfor a comment.*

Using @Saibal Mitra's example
$$\log(1+2z)=2 z-2 z^2+\frac{8 z^3}{3}-4 z^4+\frac{32 z^5}{5}-\frac{32
   z^6}{3}+\frac{128 z^7}{7}+O\left(z^8\right)$$ does not allow to do anything if $z > \frac 12$. For $z=1$, it would give the ridiculous $\frac{444}{35}$ which is $11.5$ times too large.

Using the same coefficients, consider the $[4,3]$ corresponding Padé approximant
$$\log(1+2z)=\frac{2 z+\frac{34 z^2}{7}+\frac{8 z^3}{3}+\frac{4
   z^4}{35} } { 1+\frac{24 z}{7}+\frac{24 z^2}{7}+\frac{32
   z^3}{35}}+O\left(z^8\right)$$  For $z=1$, it gives $\frac{1012}{921}$ which corresponds to a relative error of $0.018$%. For $z=2$, it leads to a relative error of $0.22$%.